# 'switch' was not found in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

[image]I am making an e-commerce website using the react js framework. I had made the home page and was trying to add routes to the other pages I was going to make. In my app file (app.js) I wrapped my header and home tags in a switch tag (<switch> </switch> ) and that's when I ran into this error. I tried uninstalling react-router-dom and reinstalling it but that didn't work . apologies if I have provided wrong / less information, I am following a YouTube video and don't really know much.

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js 14:37-43

export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await, BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_useRouteId, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, redirectDocument, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_useBlocker, unstable_usePrompt, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)
```

this is my app.js code

```
import Header from './Header'
import './App.css'
import './Header.css'
import Home from './Home'
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Switch , Route} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/'>
            <Header/>
            <Home/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What version do you use? `Switch` was removed in `6.0`

Comment: Use `<Routes>` instead of `<Switch>` ~ [_How To Fix “Switch is not exported from ‘react-router-dom’ in React” Error_](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom/)

Comment: fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Switch>` component was removed in `react-router-dom` version 6.x and replaced with `<Routes>`.

Also, you should organize your imports. Place first-party react imports at the top, followed by third-party, and finally your own components.

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';

import './App.css';
import './Header.css'; /* Should already be imported inside Header.jsx component */

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/'>
            <Header/>
            <Home/>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```